# What is wrong with my "group by" code in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

FEEDBACK table:

```
CREATE TABLE Feedback 
(
    FeedbackID nvarchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Rating SMALLINT, 
    Comments nvarchar(50), 
    MemberID nvarchar(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Member(MemberID), 
    BookID NVARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Book(BookID)
);
```

BOOK table:

```
CREATE TABLE Book  
(
    BookID nvarchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name nvarchar(50), 
    SerialNumber nvarchar(50), 
    CategoryID nvarchar(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Category(CategoryID), 
    PublisherID NVARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Publisher(PublisherID), 
    Unit_Price nvarchar(50), 
    Quantity NVARCHAR (50)
);
```

I have only managed to get this by using

```
SELECT BookID, COUNT(FeedbackID) AS Numoffeedback 
FROM Feedback 
GROUP BY BookID;

BookID | TotalNumberofFeedbacks
-------+-----------------------
```

But my desired output is this :

```
BookID | Name | TotalNumberofFeedbacks
-------+------+-----------------------
```

I tried do this

```
SELECT BookID, COUNT(FeedbackID) AS Numoffeedback 
FROM Feedback 
GROUP BY BookID, Name;
```

but i received this error "Invalid column name 'Name'.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Do you get any errors? If yes, which errors? Do you get a result that differs from you expected result? Show some example data together with your current and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the two tables together and then aggregate by book.  You may try the following query:

```sql
SELECT b.BookID, b.Name, COUNT(f.BookID) AS TotalNumberOfFeedbacks
FROM Book b
LEFT JOIN Feedback f
    ON f.BookID = b.BookID
GROUP BY b.BookID, b.Name;
```

Note that we count `f.BookID` here.  The reason for this is should a certain book have no feedback, we want the count to be zero.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking , why do I have to add b. infront of the bookID and Name ?

Comment: The `b` and `f` prefixes you see throughout the query are called _aliases_ and refer back to the respective tables containing these columns.  Look closely after the table references `Book` and `Feedback`, and you will see whence the aliases are coming.

Comment: @Diamondhands: for the `Name` column, the table alias isn't *absolutely necessary*, since `Name` only exists in `Book` - but it's still good practice to use table aliases to make it clear and obvious from which table you're selecting data. For the `BookId` column, you **must** provide a table alias - since a column by that name exists in both tables, and it would be unclear (without the alias) which table to select the `BookId` from ...

Comment: Is "LEFT JOIN" the only way to solve this problem ? Is there another way by using "Group By" ?

Comment: ... my answer _is_ using `GROUP BY`

Comment: Ohh,.. i got confused . sry

Comment: @diamondhands You want to count data in the feedback table, and display the name from the book table. How do you propose utilising data from two tables without using a join?